# Slideshow with image preload ONE at a time and delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

I want a slideshow in a page I am developing, but it contains a lot of images, with total size of over 15 MB. So it is unmanageable to preload all the images before the slideshow starts. I want the slides to fade-in and stay for 5 seconds. I want the next image to preload while the previous one is showing. Images have different dimensions, so the next image can't be hidden behind the previous one after loading. Any help?
I tried this code but no success:

```
var slidesImages = $('.slide_list img');
slidesImages.hide();
function loadMyImage(){

var image = slidesImages.eq(0);
var image_src = image.attr('data-src');

$('<img>').load(function(){

    $(".slide").hide().attr('src', image_src).fadeIn("slow");
    if(i<slidesImages.length) {
        slidesImages.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

}).attr('src',image_src);

}
var interval = window.setInterval(loadMyImage(), 5000);
```

And the html:

```
<div align="center"><img class="slide" src="imagens/loading.gif"></div>
<ul class="slide_list">
    <li><img data-src='/zenphoto/albums/pag_inicial_slideshow/20130102_164730.jpg' src='imagens/loading.gif' alt='' title='' height='300'></li>
    <li><img data-src='/zenphoto/albums/pag_inicial_slideshow/20130102_161616-2.jpg' src='imagens/loading.gif' alt='' title='' height='300'></li>
    <li><img data-src='/zenphoto/albums/pag_inicial_slideshow/20130102_161048.jpg' src='imagens/loading.gif' alt='' title='' height='300'></li>
    <li><img data-src='/zenphoto/albums/pag_inicial_slideshow/20130102_154523.jpg' src='imagens/loading.gif' alt='' title='' height='300'></li>
    <li><img data-src='/zenphoto/albums/pag_inicial_slideshow/20130102_152713.jpg' src='imagens/loading.gif' alt='' title='' height='300'></li>
    ...                 
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code a little bit, made several changes and it started to work.

```
function loadMyImage(obj){

        var image = obj.eq(0);
        var image_src = $(image).attr('data-src');

        $('<img>').load(function(){

            $(".slide").hide().attr('src', image_src).fadeIn("slow");
            if(obj.length) {
                obj.splice(0, 1);
            } else {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }

        }).attr('src',image_src);

}

$(window).load(function () {
    var slidesImages = $('.slide_list img');
    slidesImages.hide();
            var interval = window.setInterval(function () { loadMyImage(slidesImages); }, 2000);
});
```